# Mysql: query work on phpmyadmin but generate rollback on php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I write a simply query, work fine on `phpmyadmin` but if I run the same query in my php script with pdo no error was return and  after few seconds db do a (I presume) rollback canceling my update

The query:

```
UPDATE tab SET whoweare = 'text 888', services = '', logo = '', copertina = '', galleria1 = '', galleria2 = '', galleria3 = '', galleria4 = '', indirizzo = 'input 1', tel_fisso = '', tel_mobile = '', orari = 'input 4', social_www = '', social_tw = '', social_fb = '', social_yt = '', social_lin = '' WHERE users_user='try'
```

Comment: So what did PDO say the error was?

Comment: Can we see your PHP/PDO code where you are checking for errors?

Comment: no error return on pdo

Comment: ok, this is my pdo class http://nitrobits.com/file/tftvDvpZ9ybAMJ2/class.database.php.zip i use like $db->run("UPDATE..");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You miss a whitspace on your query, try this one

```
UPDATE tab SET whoweare = 'text 888', services = '', logo = '', copertina = '', galleria1 = '', galleria2 = '', galleria3 = '', galleria4 = '', indirizzo = 'input 1', tel_fisso = '', tel_mobile = '', orari = 'input 4', social_www = '', social_tw = '', social_fb = '', social_yt = '', social_lin = '' WHERE users_user='try'
```

Comment: the space is only my copy-paste error, sorry.
the script have right space before where

Comment: then you should provide more code, the query seems to be ok

Answer (score -1):

Check that your database connection is actually being opened successfully and that the user you are connecting to the database as has permission to update that table.

Comment: Wow, who would downvote an answer that says to check for errors after opening a database connection?